# How to efficiently query the most recent tasks performed by an employee?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I need to query the three most recent tasks performed by an employee from a table which includes the employee name, the task, and the timestamp. For example, for employee Adam, the most recent tasks are Filing, Typing, and Cleaning.

My current query returns accurate results, but I'd like some guidance if I have written the query in the most efficient fashion. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE TempData ( Employee VARCHAR(16), Task VARCHAR(16), TaskDate DATE );

INSERT INTO TempData VALUES 
( 'Adam', 'Filing', '2022-09-30' ),
( 'Adam', 'Filing', '2022-09-29' ),
( 'Adam', 'Filing', '2022-09-28' ),
( 'Adam', 'Typing', '2022-09-28' ),
( 'Adam', 'Typing', '2022-09-27' ),
( 'Adam', 'Typing', '2022-09-26' ),
( 'Adam', 'Cleaning', '2022-09-25' ),
( 'Adam', 'Cooking', '2022-09-24' ),
( 'Adam', 'Organizing', '2022-09-23' ),
( 'Bob', 'Typing', '2022-09-27' ),
( 'Bob', 'Baking', '2022-09-25' );


SELECT Task, (  SELECT TaskDate 
                  FROM TempData 
                 WHERE Employee = 'Adam' AND TempData.Task = TaskList.Task 
              ORDER BY TaskDate DESC LIMIT 1 ) MostRecent
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT Task FROM TempData WHERE Employee = 'Adam') TaskList
ORDER BY MostRecent DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: You don't know which task is most recent eg ('Adam', 'Filing', '2022-09-28' ),
( 'Adam', 'Typing', '2022-09-28') both are on the same day but no way of telling which is most recent,

Comment: @P.Salmon, an excellent point, thank you for identifying this. In my production environment there is a full timestamp including both date and time. In this sample data, I simply used a DATE type for simplicity. (I recognize that in this sample data, if ADAM had more than four tasks on one date, it would be impossible to tell which three are most recent). The thrust of my question is how to structure the query most efficiently....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your amalgamation of sub-queries is confusing and convoluted.  Why not just something like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/FycfYNCD)?

```
select Task, max(TaskDate) as MostRecent from TempData 
where Employee = 'Adam'
group by Task 
order by MostRecent desc 
limit 3;
```

Sub-queries are at least no more efficient than a join - but usually less efficient, especially if they're convoluted, because the sql engine has trouble optimizing them back to joins.  Consider the `explain select` for both our queries.

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | <derived3> | *null* | ALL | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 2 | 100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 3 | DERIVED | TempData | *null* | ALL | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 11 | 10.00 | Using where; Using temporary |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | TempData | *null* | ALL | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 11 | 9.09 | Using where; Using filesort |

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | TempData | *null* | ALL | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 11 | 10.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |

If you want it to be more efficient you can put an index on the table on `Employee`.

Comment: thank you - this is extremely helpful, particularly the comparison via the explain select statements